# Lewis acids as ligands

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Usually Lewis bases as my textbook says:

> **2.3 Ligands**
>   The ligands are the ions or molecules bound to the central atom/ion in the coordination entity. This is better visualized as the combination of a Lewis acid (the central atom/ion) with a number of Lewis bases (ligands). The atom of Lewis base that forms the bond to the Lewis acid (central atom/ion) is called donor atom ...

According to me its not compulsory for a ligand to be a Lewis base, as $\ce{BF3}$ is a Lewis acid and can act as a ligand by accepting electrons from a metal in vacant orbital of boron. Is it true?

Comment: In that situation, the thing that the boron is binding to is the ligand.

Comment: I can't understand. Please clarify

Comment: @Zhe Actually OP is right. Ligands can have both acceptor and donor properties like CO, or indeed be only acceptors like BF3.

Comment: Can H+ also act as ligand for electron rich metals. If it can its a pure acid . AlCl3 might also be such a ligand due to vacant d orbital of Al

Comment: @Harshjain You're going to far there. While H+ and AlCl3 are Lewis acids (and don't even mention this "d-orbital" nonsense) it's a matter of formalism when something can be called [Z-Ligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Ligand).

Comment: @Mithoron Thanks for the reference on "Z-ligands." I've not encountered those before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can happen.  [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020169300932420) offers an example, in which $\ce{BF3}$ or $\ce{B(C6F5)3}$ adds to a low oxidation state iridium complex.  There is really not a lot of mystery behind it.  The iridium in its low oxidation state has electrons to offer and the boron with its vacant orbital can take them up.